# SFTP Timeout on download

Tags: ssh, sftp, timeout, openbsd

my server keeps timing out when i attempt to download a handfull of files at once.

i'm running ubuntu 10.4 LTS

sshd_config contains the following tweaks:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group www
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and fstab contains the following tweaks:

```
/srv/www/domain.com /home/chris/domain.com none bind
```

after attempting to download the files the user will be disconnected.

i'm not even sure where to begin debugging this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: How long after initiation does it disconnect?

Comment: Is there a specific error message that goes along with the timeout? Or is it just "Connection Timed Out"?

Comment: it may download one or two files successfully and timeout when 5 or more are simultaneously queued. operation timed out. connection closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out it was a misconfiguration with fail to ban, involving both ssh keys and pw checks. for sftp, the key's failed, resulting in a ten minute ban.